# JS After logging out Facebook App, .getLoginStatus still returns "connected"

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk

I have implemented JS SDK Facebook login into my website. It seems like the FacebookSDK keeps logged in even after the user is logged out of his Facebook Account.  Basically the user is already logged out of Facebook but the FB.getLoginStatus still returns connected.

Any ideas? Thank you :)

```
var fbLogin = function() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                ---- !!!! jumps here even after the user logged out :(
            } else {
                
            }
        }, true);
    };

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: facebook_login_id,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            user_email: true
        });

        fbLogin();
    };
```

Same error is mentioned here: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/620